# Javascript weird random behavior

Tags: javascript, canvas, random, distribution

I'm using JavaScript's `Math.random()` function to distribute items over buckets.
Afterwards, I display the buckets in a canvas. I would expect the items to be distributed evenly, but (even after multiple retries in multiple browsers), it seems like the distribution is much more fine grained on the left (closer to zero) and becomes more uniform towards the right (closer to 1). See the following image [image].

Am I doing it wrong, or does JavaScript's random function suck? Below is the code that was used to generate this image:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    var width = canvas.width;
                    var height = canvas.height;     
                    var buckets = width;
                    var total = width*height*0.3;
                    var bucketList = [];
                    // initialized each bucket to 0 items
                    for(var i=0; i<buckets; ++i) { 
                            bucketList[i] = 0;  
                    }
                    // distribute all items over the buckets
                    for(var i=0; i<total; ++i) {
                        ++bucketList[Math.floor(Math.random()*buckets)];
                    }
                    // draw the buckets
                    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
                    for(var i=0; i<buckets; ++i) {
                        ctx.fillRect (i, height-bucketList[i], i+1, height);  
                    }
            }
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <canvas id="canvas" width="1000px" height="500px"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `ctx.fillRect (i, height-bucketList[i], i+1, height);` should be                         `ctx.fillRect (i, height-bucketList[i], 1, height);`

Comment: +1 for asking this question perfectly.  It's clearly worded, the code is complete, easy to follow, and clean, and the image shows exactly what's happening.  The the question itself is interesting and relevant.  Thank you!

Comment: @AdamLiss he plotted the numbers incorrectly...

Comment: @xiaoyi nonetheless, the format of the question is notably well written.

Comment: With the fix suggested by @xiaoyi in place, the picture looks quite random to me: http://jsfiddle.net/TvNJw/

Comment: Do you get the same anomalous distribution in all browsers? `Math.random` is described in the spec with no implementation details, but practically, most browsers seed the PRNG with a date stamp. It would be interesting to see if this is happening in all browsers or just very fast ones.

Comment: updated @AlexanderPavlov's fiddle with wider bucket http://jsfiddle.net/TvNJw/1/ Now it looks almost evenly distributed.

Comment: Thanks @xiaoyi, this looks much better. Yet, I've found [this article](http://baagoe.com/en/RandomMusings/javascript/) covering some of the `Math.random()` details, which explains why it is still not so good as a true PRNG.

Comment: i agree that the ploting is wrong too, all rects end at max width (you can better see it if you stroke the rect's instead of fill).
also dont understand the for(var i=0; i<total; ++i) you are initializing a LOT of rectangles...

Comment: I had confused the function's API, assuming that the third and fourth parameter would not be width and height, but the coordinates of another point. Thus the code should have been `ctx.fillRect (i, height-bucketList[i], 1, bucketList[i]);`. Obviously, I totally misinterpreted the generated result. It is planned that the code visualize a proof from "The Art of Programming" in the "Multiway Merging and Replacement Selection" section.

Comment: Here is the final version http://jsfiddle.net/m4UNb/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me respond with an answer, since my comment on the question has a great chance to be lost among its neighbors.

So, with the fix suggested by @xiaoyi in place, the picture looks quite random to me: http://jsfiddle.net/TvNJw. The plotting routine originally suggested in the question wrongly increases the painted bucket width as `i` grows, while all buckets should have the width of `1`. This can easily be depicted by plotting buckets with different colors.